# Magento: Add captcha to custom contact form

Tags: magento-1.8, configuration, custom, contact-us

I created a new custom contact form in Magento website, I am trying to add captcha at the end of it.

I have added to app/code/core/Mage/Captcha/etc/config.xml

```
                <customcontacts>
                    <label>Custom Contact Form</label>
                </customcontacts>
```

And I added to app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/captcha.xml

```
    <customcontacts>
    <reference name="customcontacts">
        <block type="core/text_list" name="form.additional.info">
            <block type="captcha/captcha" name="captcha">
                <reference name="head">
                    <action method="addJs"><file>mage/captcha.js</file></action>
                </reference>
                <action method="setFormId"><formId>customcontacts</formId></action>
                <action method="setImgWidth"><width>230</width></action>
                <action method="setImgHeight"><width>50</width></action>
            </block>
        </block>
    </reference>
</customcontacts>
```

And I added to my form this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
$('form-validate-captcha').captcha.refresh($('catpcha-reload'));
//]]>
```

And I added this code to show the Captcha:

```
<div><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('captcha'); ?></div>
```

Then I enabled Captcha in Configuration > Customer Configuration > CAPTCHA and I choose "Custom Contact Form" then "Displaying Mode" to "Always".

But I still didn't get the Captcha at my custom form yet.

I hope I was clear

Thanks

Comment: Free extension https://magecomp.com/magento-new-recaptcha.html

Answer (score 13):

**NameSpace : MyPackage and Module: MyModule**

Module configuration

location : app/etc/modules/MyPackage_MyModule.xml

```
<config>
<modules>
    <MyPackage_MyModule>
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>local</codePool>
    </MyPackage_MyModule>
</modules>
```

Create config file for this module

location : app/code/local/MyPackage/MyModule/etc/config.xml

```
<config>
<modules>
    <MyPackage_MyModule>
        <version>0.0.0.1</version>
    </MyPackage_MyModule>
</modules>
<global>
    <models>
        <mymodule>
            <class>MyPackage_MyModule_Model</class>
        </mymodule>
    </models>
    <events>
        <controller_action_predispatch_contacts_index_post>
            <observers>
                <mymodule>
                    <class>mymodule/observer</class>
                    <method>checkContacts</method>
                </mymodule>
            </observers>
        </controller_action_predispatch_contacts_index_post>
    </events>
</global>
<default>
    <captcha>
        <frontend>
            <areas>
                <contacts>
                    <label>Contacts Page</label>
                </contacts>
            </areas>
        </frontend>
    </captcha>
    <customer>
        <captcha>
            <always_for>
                <contacts>1</contacts>
            </always_for>
        </captcha>
    </customer>
</default>
```

Create a observer for that

location: app/code/local/MyPackage/MyModule/Model/Observer.php

```
class MyPackage_MyModule_Model_Observer
{
    public function checkContacts($observer){
        $formId = 'contacts';
        $captchaModel = Mage::helper('captcha')->getCaptcha($formId);
        if ($captchaModel->isRequired()) {
            $controller = $observer->getControllerAction();
            $word = $this->_getCaptchaString($controller->getRequest(), $formId);
            if (!$captchaModel->isCorrect($word)) {
                Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addError(Mage::helper('captcha')->__('Incorrect CAPTCHA.'));
                $controller->setFlag('', Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::FLAG_NO_DISPATCH, true);
                $url =  Mage::getUrl('contacts');
                $controller->getResponse()->setRedirect($url);
            }
        }
        return $this;
    }
    /**
     * Get Captcha String
     *
     * @param Varien_Object $request
     * @param string $formId
     * @return string
     */
    protected function _getCaptchaString($request, $formId)
    {
        $captchaParams = $request->getPost(Mage_Captcha_Helper_Data::INPUT_NAME_FIELD_VALUE);
        return $captchaParams[$formId];
    }
}
```

Create a local.xml to your active theme inside layout folder.

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
<contacts_index_index>
    <reference name="contactForm">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>mymodule/contacts/form.phtml</template></action>
        <block type="core/text_list" name="form.additional.info">
            <block type="captcha/captcha" name="captcha">
                <reference name="head">
                    <action method="addJs"><file>mage/captcha.js</file></action>
                </reference>
                <action method="setFormId"><formId>contacts</formId></action>
                <action method="setImgWidth"><width>230</width></action>
                <action method="setImgHeight"><width>50</width></action>
            </block>
        </block>
    </reference>
</contacts_index_index>
```

Now copy contacts/form.phtml to mymodule/contacts/form.phtml, add `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('form.additional.info'); ?>` your requirement. example...

```
<li class="wide">
            <label for="comment" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Comment') ?></label>
            <div class="input-box">
                <textarea name="comment" id="comment" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Comment') ?>" class="required-entry input-text" cols="5" rows="3"></textarea>
            </div>
        </li>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('form.additional.info'); ?>
    </ul>
```

Clear cache.
Now Go to **System -> Configuration -> Customer Configuration -> Captcha**. Select **Contact Page** and Save.

Comment: What was the version(s) of Magento this solution is made for? ... was it for Magento 1.9.*

Comment: Awesome - thanks. Worked for me on 1.8.1.0

Comment: this did not worked for me, because you need to extend mage captcha block to get html to your form.. this link helped me: https://www.atwix.com/magento/captcha-in-magento/

Answer (score 3):

Not an answer to your question, but you should have a look on [HoneySpam](https://github.com/magento-hackathon/HoneySpam). It uses other spam-avoiding techniques which don't annoy customers.

Comment: I second that. I used HoneySpam and was happy with the results.

Answer (score 1):

as per i have done as below. it works for me.

**layout.xml**

```
<reference name="content">
    <block type="customer/form_register" name="multivendor_customer_form_register" template="multivendor/form/register.phtml">
        <action method="setShowAddressFields"><value>true</value></action>
        <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="multivendor.customer.form.register.fields.before" as="multivendor_form_fields_before" translate="label">
            <label>Form Fields Before</label>
        </block>


        <!-- Code Start For Display Captcha on Register page -->
        <block type="captcha/captcha" name="captcha">
                <reference name="head">
                    <action method="addJs"><file>mage/captcha.js</file></action>
                </reference>
                <action method="setFormId"><formId>vendor_form</formId></action>
                <action method="setImgWidth"><width>230</width></action>
                <action method="setImgHeight"><width>50</width></action>
        </block> 
        <!-- Code End For Display Captcha on Register page-->


    </block>
</reference>
```

**form.phtml**

```
<div class="field">
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('captcha'); ?>
</div>
```

**controller.php in submit action (where your form submitted)**

```
//Captcha Checking Start
$formId = 'vendor_form';
$captchaModel = Mage::helper('captcha')->getCaptcha($formId);
if ($captchaModel->isRequired()) {
    $captchaModel = Mage::helper('captcha')->getCaptcha($formId);
    if ($captchaModel->isRequired()) {
        if (!$captchaModel->isCorrect($this->_getCaptchaString($this->getRequest(), $formId))) {
            Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError(Mage::helper('captcha')->__('Incorrect CAPTCHA.'));
            $this->_redirectReferer('');
            return;
        }
    }
}
//Captcha Checking End
```

Enjoy it works great.

Answer (score 1):

Solution by Sohel Rana worked, except the first XML is missing a < /config > tag.

Other things to note is that Captcha need to be turned on in system configuration as well.

The contact form should be access via /contacts URL and not through a CMS page content with {{block}} set up. The CMS content {{block}} can't get updated with the XML layout to insert the captcha.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use core captcha functionality in contact us form you need to develop a module in your local directory.
Here “Compny” is my namespace and “Captcha” is module name

First of all create module config file Compny_Captcha.xml in app/etc/modules/

```
<?xml version=”1.0″?>
<config>
<modules>
<Compny_Captcha>
<active>true</active>
<codePool>local</codePool>
<depends>
<Mage_Captcha/>
</depends>
</Compny_Captcha>
</modules>
</config>
```

create module config.xml file in app/code/local/Compny/Captcha/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version=”1.0″?>

<config>
<modules>
<Compny_Captcha>
<version>1.8.0.0.0</version>
</Compny_Captcha>
</modules>
<global>
<models>
<captcha>
<rewrite>
<zend>Compny_Captcha_Model_Zend</zend>
</rewrite>
</captcha>
</models>
</global>
<default>
<captcha  translate=”label”>
<frontend>
<areas>
<contact_us>
<label>Contact us Form</label>
</contact_us>
</areas>
</frontend>
</captcha>

<customer>
<captcha>
<always_for>
<contact_us>1</contact_us>
</always_for>
</captcha>
</customer>
</default>
<frontend>
<routers>
<contacts>
<args>
<modules>
<Compny_captcha before=”Mage_Contacts”>Compny_Captcha</Compny_captcha>
</modules>
</args>
</contacts>
</routers>
</frontend>
</config>
```

Here You can override core captcha model because captcha is not appear after customer login if you want to display captcha after customer login so you need to override Mage_Captcha_Model_Zend file _isUserAuth() function
create Zend.php file in app/code/local/Compny/Captcha/Model/Zend.php

```
<?php

class Compny_Captcha_Model_Zend extends Mage_Captcha_Model_Zend
{

protected function _isUserAuth()
{
//die(‘function called’);
/* return Mage::app()->getStore()->isAdmin()
? Mage::getSingleton(‘admin/session’)->isLoggedIn()
: Mage::getSingleton(‘customer/session’)->isLoggedIn();*/
}

}
```

In this function you need to only comment function code.

Now create frontend layout you need to edit contacts.xml in app/design/frontend/default/default/layout/contacts.xml
Here you need to add captcha block under

```
<reference name=”content”>
<block type=”core/template” name=”contactForm” template=”contacts/form.phtml”>

<block type=”core/text_list” name=”form.additional.info”>
<block type=”captcha/captcha” name=”captcha”>
<reference name=”head”>
<action method=”addJs”><file>mage/captcha.js</file></action>
</reference>
<action method=”setFormId”><formId>contact_us</formId></action>
<action method=”setImgWidth”><width>230</width></action>
<action method=”setImgHeight”><width>50</width></action>
</block>
</block>

</block>
</reference>
```

After that you need to call block in frontend form.phtml file in app/design/frontend/default/default/template/contacts/form.phtml
you just put the below line before completing `</ul>` tag

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml(‘form.additional.info’); ?>
```

Now you need to override contact us controller create file in  app/code/local/Compny/Captcha/controllers/IndexController.php

```
<?php
require_once(Mage::getModuleDir(‘controllers’,’Mage_Contacts’).DS.’IndexController.php’);
class Compny_Captcha_IndexController extends Mage_Contacts_IndexController
{

public function postAction()
{
$post = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
if ( $post ) {
$translate = Mage::getSingleton(‘core/translate’);
/* @var $translate Mage_Core_Model_Translate */
$translate->setTranslateInline(false);
try {
$postObject = new Varien_Object();
$postObject->setData($post);

$error = false;

if (!Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['name']) , ‘NotEmpty’)) {
$error = true;
}

if (!Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['comment']) , ‘NotEmpty’)) {
$error = true;
}

if (!Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['email']), ‘EmailAddress’)) {
$error = true;
}

if (Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['hideit']), ‘NotEmpty’)) {
$error = true;
}

$formId =’contact_us’;
$captchaModel = Mage::helper(‘captcha’)->getCaptcha($formId);
if ($captchaModel->isRequired()) {
if (!$captchaModel->isCorrect($this->_getCaptchaString($this->getRequest(), $formId))) {
Mage::getSingleton(‘customer/session’)->addError(Mage::helper(‘captcha’)->__(‘Incorrect CAPTCHA.’));
$this->setFlag(”, Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::FLAG_NO_DISPATCH, true);
Mage::getSingleton(‘customer/session’)->setCustomerFormData($this->getRequest()->getPost());
$this->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl(‘*/*/’));
return;
}
}

if ($error) {
throw new Exception();
}
$mailTemplate = Mage::getModel(‘core/email_template’);
/* @var $mailTemplate Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template */
$mailTemplate->setDesignConfig(array(‘area’ => ‘frontend’))
->setReplyTo($post['email'])
->sendTransactional(
Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE),
Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_SENDER),
Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT),
null,
array(‘data’ => $postObject)
);

if (!$mailTemplate->getSentSuccess()) {
throw new Exception();
}

$translate->setTranslateInline(true);

Mage::getSingleton(‘customer/session’)->addSuccess(Mage::helper(‘contacts’)->__(‘Your inquiry was submitted and will be responded to as soon as possible. Thank you for contacting us.’));
$this->_redirect(‘*/*/’);

return;
} catch (Exception $e) {
$translate->setTranslateInline(true);

Mage::getSingleton(‘customer/session’)->addError(Mage::helper(‘contacts’)->__(‘Unable to submit your request. Please, try again later’));
$this->_redirect(‘*/*/’);
return;
}

} else {
$this->_redirect(‘*/*/’);
}
}

protected function _getCaptchaString($request, $formId)
{
$captchaParams = $request->getPost(Mage_Captcha_Helper_Data::INPUT_NAME_FIELD_VALUE);
return $captchaParams[$formId];
}

}
```

Now the captcha module is ready to test..

To apply captcha in contact us form go to your admin panel setting **system->configuration->customer configuration->Captcha**
Enable captcha if it disable you can see “Contact us Form” in multiselect form area select it and save configuration. see your captcha  on front-end.

Comment: @SINHI S, I did exactly as said but unfortunately it is not even show in configuration, I am sure I did something wrong I don't know hoe to explain, I hope I can show you how I have done it, Thank you

Comment: Can you verify, have you created all folders with the right name.

Comment: Then logout from admin and again login to admin, try flush cache and clear cache...

Comment: I did exactly same folder names, and I logout and log in from admin, and still I see same options: Create User, login, Forget password, Checkout as guest, and Register during Checkout and the new one not show

Answer (score 0):

Here are the free Magento extensions for Easy Contact Form Captcha
Download from here:-  [free Magento extensions](https://www.envisionecommerce.com/store/free-items/free-magentor-extensions.html)

[image: config of extension]