# Add Captcha to customer registration form

Tags: magento-1.9, customer-account, captcha

i have one extesnion for vendor. when customer create account it shows this vendor register form in which i want to use captcha.

i used [this reference link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/18620/1927) for capthca. captcha shows bt not working.

**Config.xml**

```
<events>
        <controller_action_predispatch_multivendor_vendor_captcha>
             <observers>
                <multivendor>
                    <class>multivendor/Captchaobserver</class>
                    <method>checkCaptcha</method>
                </multivendor>
            </observers> 
        </controller_action_predispatch_multivendor_vendor_captcha>
    </events>
```

**multivendor.xml**

```
<multivendor_vendor_signup>
     <label>Customer Account Registration Form</label>
    <!-- Mage_Customer -->
    <remove name="right"/>
    <remove name="left"/>

    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="customer/form_register" name="multivendor_customer_form_register" template="multivendor/form/register.phtml">
            <action method="setShowAddressFields"><value>true</value></action>
            <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="multivendor.customer.form.register.fields.before" as="multivendor_form_fields_before" translate="label">
                <label>Form Fields Before</label>

            </block>

            <block type="captcha/captcha" name="captcha">
                    <reference name="head">
                        <action method="addJs"><file>mage/captcha.js</file></action>
                    </reference>
                    <action method="setFormId"><formId>contact_form</formId></action>
                    <action method="setImgWidth"><width>230</width></action>
                    <action method="setImgHeight"><width>50</width></action>
            </block> 
        </block>
    </reference>
</multivendor_vendor_signup>
```

**Observer.php**

```
class CompanyName_MultiVendor_Model_Captchaobserver
{

    protected function _getCaptchaString($request, $formId)
    {
        $captchaParams = $request->getPost(Mage_Captcha_Helper_Data::INPUT_NAME_FIELD_VALUE);
        return $captchaParams[$formId];
    }

    /**
     * Break the execution in case of incorrect CAPTCHA
     *
     * @param Varien_Event_Observer $observer
     * @return Your_Module_Model_Observer
     */
    public function checkCaptcha($observer)
    {
    $formId = 'contact_form';
    $captchaModel = Mage::helper('captcha')->getCaptcha($formId);
    if ($captchaModel->isRequired()) {
        $controller = $observer->getControllerAction();
        if (!$captchaModel->isCorrect($this->_getCaptchaString($controller->getRequest(), $formId))) {
            Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addError(Mage::helper('captcha')->__('Incorrect CAPTCHA.'));
            $controller->setFlag('', Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::FLAG_NO_DISPATCH, true);
            Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->setCustomerFormData($controller->getRequest()->getPost());
            $controller->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('*/*/signup'));
        }
    }

    return $this;
}
```

}

Comment: Free one https://magecomp.com/magento-new-recaptcha.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**layout.xml**

```
<reference name="content">
    <block type="customer/form_register" name="multivendor_customer_form_register" template="multivendor/form/register.phtml">
        <action method="setShowAddressFields"><value>true</value></action>
        <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="multivendor.customer.form.register.fields.before" as="multivendor_form_fields_before" translate="label">
            <label>Form Fields Before</label>
        </block>


        <!-- Code Start For Display Captcha on Register page -->
        <block type="captcha/captcha" name="captcha">
                <reference name="head">
                    <action method="addJs"><file>mage/captcha.js</file></action>
                </reference>
                <action method="setFormId"><formId>vendor_form</formId></action>
                <action method="setImgWidth"><width>230</width></action>
                <action method="setImgHeight"><width>50</width></action>
        </block> 
        <!-- Code End For Display Captcha on Register page-->


    </block>
</reference>
```

**form.phtml**

```
<div class="field">
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('captcha'); ?>
</div>
```

**controller.php in submit action (where your form submitted)**

```
//Captcha Checking Start
$formId = 'vendor_form';
$captchaModel = Mage::helper('captcha')->getCaptcha($formId);
if ($captchaModel->isRequired()) {
    $captchaModel = Mage::helper('captcha')->getCaptcha($formId);
    if ($captchaModel->isRequired()) {
        if (!$captchaModel->isCorrect($this->_getCaptchaString($this->getRequest(), $formId))) {
            Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError(Mage::helper('captcha')->__('Incorrect CAPTCHA.'));
            $this->_redirectReferer('');
            return;
        }
    }
}
//Captcha Checking End
```

Enjoy it works great.