# Magento1.9 : How to add Captcha to custom form

Tags: magento-1.9, captcha

I have created a cms page named "custom" ad this page has content `{{block type="core/template"  template="my/custom.phtml"}}`. And in custom.phtml created a custom form with custom validation and custom controller action for submission.

Now I want to add captcha to this form.

For this I have added below xml script to cms xml field :

```
<reference name="content">
    <!-- Code Start For Display Captcha -->
    <block type="captcha/captcha" name="captcha">
            <reference name="head">
                <action method="addJs"><file>mage/captcha.js</file></action>
            </reference>
            <action method="setFormId"><formId>form-validate</formId></action>
            <action method="setImgWidth"><width>230</width></action>
            <action method="setImgHeight"><width>50</width></action>
    </block> 
    <!-- Code End For Display Captcha -->


</reference>
```

And `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('captcha'); ?>` on custom.phtml file.

But captcha not appearing on page.

How to resolve it?

Comment: Try this https://magecomp.com/magento-new-recaptcha.html

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at this answer

[Magento: Add captcha to custom contact form](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/18620/48571)

**NameSpace : MyPackage and Module: MyModule**

Module configuration

location : app/etc/modules/MyPackage_MyModule.xml

```
<config>
<modules>
    <MyPackage_MyModule>
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>local</codePool>
    </MyPackage_MyModule>
</modules>
```

Create config file for this module

location : app/code/local/MyPackage/MyModule/etc/config.xml

```
<config>
<modules>
    <MyPackage_MyModule>
        <version>0.0.0.1</version>
    </MyPackage_MyModule>
</modules>
<global>
    <models>
        <mymodule>
            <class>MyPackage_MyModule_Model</class>
        </mymodule>
    </models>
    <events>
        <controller_action_predispatch_contacts_index_post>
            <observers>
                <mymodule>
                    <class>mymodule/observer</class>
                    <method>checkContacts</method>
                </mymodule>
            </observers>
        </controller_action_predispatch_contacts_index_post>
    </events>
</global>
<default>
    <captcha>
        <frontend>
            <areas>
                <contacts>
                    <label>Contacts Page</label>
                </contacts>
            </areas>
        </frontend>
    </captcha>
    <customer>
        <captcha>
            <always_for>
                <contacts>1</contacts>
            </always_for>
        </captcha>
    </customer>
</default>
```

Create a observer for that

location: app/code/local/MyPackage/MyModule/Model/Observer.php

```
class MyPackage_MyModule_Model_Observer
{
    public function checkContacts($observer){
        $formId = 'contacts';
        $captchaModel = Mage::helper('captcha')->getCaptcha($formId);
        if ($captchaModel->isRequired()) {
            $controller = $observer->getControllerAction();
            $word = $this->_getCaptchaString($controller->getRequest(), $formId);
            if (!$captchaModel->isCorrect($word)) {
                Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addError(Mage::helper('captcha')->__('Incorrect CAPTCHA.'));
                $controller->setFlag('', Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::FLAG_NO_DISPATCH, true);
                $url =  Mage::getUrl('contacts');
                $controller->getResponse()->setRedirect($url);
            }
        }
        return $this;
    }
    /**
     * Get Captcha String
     *
     * @param Varien_Object $request
     * @param string $formId
     * @return string
     */
    protected function _getCaptchaString($request, $formId)
    {
        $captchaParams = $request->getPost(Mage_Captcha_Helper_Data::INPUT_NAME_FIELD_VALUE);
        return $captchaParams[$formId];
    }
}
```

Create a local.xml to your active theme inside layout folder.

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
<contacts_index_index>
    <reference name="contactForm">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>mymodule/contacts/form.phtml</template></action>
        <block type="core/text_list" name="form.additional.info">
            <block type="captcha/captcha" name="captcha">
                <reference name="head">
                    <action method="addJs"><file>mage/captcha.js</file></action>
                </reference>
                <action method="setFormId"><formId>contacts</formId></action>
                <action method="setImgWidth"><width>230</width></action>
                <action method="setImgHeight"><width>50</width></action>
            </block>
        </block>
    </reference>
</contacts_index_index>
```

Now copy contacts/form.phtml to mymodule/contacts/form.phtml, add `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('form.additional.info'); ?>` your requirement. example...

```
<li class="wide">
            <label for="comment" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Comment') ?></label>
            <div class="input-box">
                <textarea name="comment" id="comment" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Comment') ?>" class="required-entry input-text" cols="5" rows="3"></textarea>
            </div>
        </li>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('form.additional.info'); ?>
    </ul>
```

Clear cache.
Now Go to **System -> Configuration -> Customer Configuration -> Captcha**. Select **Contact Page** and Save.

Comment: when you copy paste someone's answer you should give credit to the original author. https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/18620/20064

Comment: @Piyush I agree with you!!!...

Comment: @Piyush Hello brother, I didn't copy paste it now. Once I was looking for the answer and yes I got the answer from the link which you've mentioned above. I just noted down this answer in my notes. And today when I saw this question , I wrote the answer from my saved notes.

Comment: @DineshYadav, As I mentioned I have created a CMS page (actually I have 5 cms page with different promotions for customer registration) and want to add xml for those cms pages not for `contact_index_index`, Can you please update your post for my case?

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/110517)

Comment: @PrincePatel I have added the code also. Thanks for suggestion. :)

Comment: Yr Wlcm.... +10 from me :)

Comment: @DineshYadav, I don't want to add xml for `contacts_index_index`, I didn't get from your code how to update xml for my cms page (where form has been created), please check my previous comment also.

Comment: @VinayaMaheshwari Create your custom controller and layout. Then call your phtml file in your custom layout instead of calling in cms page.

Comment: @DineshYadav, Ok. Can you please explain `<captcha>
        <frontend>
            <areas>
                <contacts>
                    <label>Contacts Page</label>
                </contacts>
            </areas>
        </frontend>
    </captcha>`, `name="contactForm"` and `<formId>contacts</formId>`. How do I update these in my context?

Comment: **contacts** is form id here. You have to use your form id.

Comment: How can I apply the same code for a CMS Page? I'm loading the Contact form inside a CMS Page. I have: www.domain.com/contact , and here I load the contact form using: {{block type="core/template" name="contactForm" form_action="/contacts/index/post" template="contacts/form.phtml"}} . Thanks.

Comment: @DineshYadav, Same issue for me, I have loaded contact form in footer, how can we show captcha there?

Comment: @jafarpinjar I have not tried it but you can set the template in the footer by changing the reference container to "footer" in layout.

Comment: @DineshYadav, Already template is loading in footer with contact form, just i need to show captcha over there like in the contact us page form

Comment: @jafarpinjar Did you call `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('form.additional.info'); ?>` in your phtml file?

Comment: @DineshYadav, Yes i called it, but captcha is not showing, where as its showing in contact us page

Comment: So you want to show captcha in every page?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97413/discussion-between-jafar-pinjar-and-dinesh-yadav).