# Magento 1: How to add captcha on a custom page

Tags: magento-1.9, captcha, contact-form

I found an app that adds a captcha to the contact page - it works well.

But it doesn't add it to the other custom forms I've built.

```
<layout version="0.1.0">


<contacts_index_index translate="label">
    <reference name="content">

        <reference name="contactForm">
            <action method="setTemplate"> 
                <template>contacts/contactscaptcha.phtml</template>
            </action>
            <block type="core/text_list" name="form.additional.info" >
                <block type="captcha/captcha" name="captcha">
                    <reference name="head">
                        <action method="addJs"><file>mage/captcha.js</file></action>
                    </reference>
                    <action method="setFormId"><formId>contact_us</formId></action>
                    <action method="setImgWidth"><width>230</width></action>
                    <action method="setImgHeight"><width>50</width></action>
                </block>
            </block>
        </reference>



    </reference>
</contacts_index_index>
```

My thinking was to add something like:

```
    <formABPOA translate="label">
    <reference name="content">

        <reference name="formABPOA">
            <action method="setTemplate"> 
                <template>contacts/formABPOA.phtml</template>
            </action>
            <block type="core/text_list" name="form.additional.info" >
                <block type="captcha/captcha" name="captcha">
                    <reference name="head">
                        <action method="addJs"><file>mage/captcha.js</file></action>
                    </reference>
                    <action method="setFormId"><formId>formABPOA</formId></action>
                    <action method="setImgWidth"><width>230</width></action>
                    <action method="setImgHeight"><width>50</width></action>
                </block>
            </block>
        </reference>


    </reference>
</formABPOA>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check with below url - Add you custom page in admin like below url.

https://www.eglobeits.com/blog/magento-captcha-in-contact-us-form-and-custom-forms/

its very simple way to add captcha in custom page.

I hope its work for you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create module in order to add captcha in custom form. After creating module you need go to System -> Configuration -> Customer Configuration -> Captcha -> Select Contact Page and Save

First add this file `app/etc/modules/MyPackage_MyModule.xml`

```
<config>
<modules>
    <MyPackage_MyModule>
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>local</codePool>
    </MyPackage_MyModule>
</modules>
```

After that Create configuration file for your module

Path: `app/code/local/MyPackage/MyModule/etc/config.xml`

```
<config>
<modules>
    <MyPackage_MyModule>
        <version>0.0.0.1</version>
    </MyPackage_MyModule>
</modules>
<global>
    <models>
        <mymodule>
            <class>MyPackage_MyModule_Model</class>
        </mymodule>
    </models>
    <events>
        <controller_action_predispatch_contacts_index_post>
            <observers>
                <mymodule>
                    <class>mymodule/observer</class>
                    <method>checkContacts</method>
                </mymodule>
            </observers>
        </controller_action_predispatch_contacts_index_post>
    </events>
</global>
<default>
    <captcha>
        <frontend>
            <areas>
                <contacts>
                    <label>Contacts Page</label>
                </contacts>
            </areas>
        </frontend>
    </captcha>
    <customer>
        <captcha>
            <always_for>
                <contacts>1</contacts>
            </always_for>
        </captcha>
    </customer>
</default>
```

You also need to create a observer for that

Path should be: `app/code/local/MyPackage/MyModule/Model/Observer.php`

```
class MyPackage_MyModule_Model_Observer
{
    public function checkContacts($observer){
        $formId = 'contacts';
        $captchaModel = Mage::helper('captcha')->getCaptcha($formId);
        if ($captchaModel->isRequired()) {
            $controller = $observer->getControllerAction();
            $word = $this->_getCaptchaString($controller->getRequest(), $formId);
            if (!$captchaModel->isCorrect($word)) {
                Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addError(Mage::helper('captcha')->__('Incorrect CAPTCHA.'));
                $controller->setFlag('', Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::FLAG_NO_DISPATCH, true);
                $url =  Mage::getUrl('contacts');
                $controller->getResponse()->setRedirect($url);
            }
        }
        return $this;
    }
    /**
     * Get Captcha String
     *
     * @param Varien_Object $request
     * @param string $formId
     * @return string
     */
    protected function _getCaptchaString($request, $formId)
    {
        $captchaParams = $request->getPost(Mage_Captcha_Helper_Data::INPUT_NAME_FIELD_VALUE);
        return $captchaParams[$formId];
    }
}
```

Create a local.xml  in your layout folder of active theme.

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
<contacts_index_index>
    <reference name="contactForm">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>mymodule/contacts/form.phtml</template></action>
        <block type="core/text_list" name="form.additional.info">
            <block type="captcha/captcha" name="captcha">
                <reference name="head">
                    <action method="addJs"><file>mage/captcha.js</file></action>
                </reference>
                <action method="setFormId"><formId>contacts</formId></action>
                <action method="setImgWidth"><width>230</width></action>
                <action method="setImgHeight"><width>50</width></action>
            </block>
        </block>
    </reference>
</contacts_index_index>
```

Now copy `contacts/form.phtml` to `mymodule/contacts/form.phtml`, add `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('form.additional.info'); ?>`

```
<li class="wide">
            <label for="comment" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Comment') ?></label>
            <div class="input-box">
                <textarea name="comment" id="comment" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Comment') ?>" class="required-entry input-text" cols="5" rows="3"></textarea>
            </div>
        </li>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('form.additional.info'); ?>
    </ul>
```

At last Clear your cache.

**I hope this will help**

Comment: I have this already and it works well on the contact page.

But I cant get my head around getting in on a 2nd page?

contacts/formABPOA.phtml

form.additional.info is added, observer is added, config its added as well.

Answer (score 1):

I think this link [Magento: Add captcha to custom contact form](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/18618/magento-add-captcha-to-custom-contact-form/18620#18620) should be work for you. Using @sohel rana's answer you can able to add captcha in anywhere in your custom form. Thanks.