# Magento2 Captcha not displayed when contact form is added to custom block

Tags: magento2, captcha, contact-form

I have enabled captcha using configuration `STORES > Configuration > CUSTOMERS > Customer Configuration > Captcha`

I am using one custom form which I used templates directly like below as I have to customize existing contact form on another page. [phtml file]

```
 <?php echo
 $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Contact\Block\ContactForm')
 ->setTemplate('Magento_Contact::contact_sticky.phtml')->toHtml();
 ?>
```

Captcha is showing on default page /contact but on my custom page, it is not showing.

**contact_sticky.phtml**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

?>
 <div class="block block-customer">
    <div class="block-title">
        <strong>
            <span class="text"><?php echo __('Contact us') ?></span>
        </strong>
    </div>
    <div class="block-content">
        <form class="form contact"
              action="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getFormAction(); ?>"
              id="contact-form"
              method="post"
              data-hasrequired="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('* Required Fields') ?>"
              data-mage-init='{"validation":{}}'>
            <fieldset class="fieldset contactus">
                <div class="field name required">
                    <div class="control">
                        <input placeholder="<?php echo __('Your Name*')?>" name="name" id="name" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Name') ?>" value="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($this->helper('Magento\Contact\Helper\Data')->getUserName()) ?>" class="input-text" type="text" data-validate="{required:true}"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="field email required">
                    <div class="control">
                        <input placeholder="<?php echo __('Your Email*')?>" name="email" id="email" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Email') ?>" value="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($this->helper('Magento\Contact\Helper\Data')->getUserEmail()) ?>" class="input-text" type="email" data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-email':true}"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="field telephone">
                    <div class="control">
                        <input placeholder="<?php echo __('Your Phone')?>" name="telephone" id="telephone" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Phone Number') ?>" value="" class="input-text" type="text" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php echo $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId('contact-additional-fields')->toHtml();?>
                <div class="field comment required">
                    <div class="control">
                        <textarea placeholder="<?php echo __('Your Message*')?>" name="comment" id="comment" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('What’s on your mind?') ?>" class="input-text" cols="5" rows="3" data-validate="{required:true}"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('form.additional.info'); ?>
            </fieldset>
            <div class="actions-toolbar">
                <div class="primary">
                    <input type="hidden" name="hideit" id="hideit" value="" />
                    <button type="submit" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Send Message') ?>" class="action submit primary">
                        <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Send Message') ?></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You may need to create a new setting to enable the custom page in the System -> Configuration -> Customer Configuration -> Captcha. Select Contact Page.  Check this solution https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/18618/magento-add-captcha-to-custom-contact-form

Comment: @BalaVaradarajan your provided link answer is for magento1.

Comment: For Magento 2 - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/133238/magento-2-how-to-add-captcha-to-a-custom-form

Comment: @RizwanKhan Did you able to solve it?