# Magento 1.9 - How do I get default captcha in custom template file?

Tags: magento-1.9, custom, forms, form-validation, captcha

I had created a custom template file for a custom newsletter subscription form for my Magento 1.9 store, How do I get magento default captcha in that form?

Is there any way to call default captcha in any of the custom template form in Magento 1.9?

Comment: Please refer the link. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/18618/magento-add-captcha-to-custom-contact-form/18620#18620

Comment: I created this module but the captcha doesn't displayed on my custom frontend form.